# How to remove syntax autocomplete in sublimetext2?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

I am new to coding and started using sublimetext2. I am currently mastering C, do not have problems with text autocompletes, but the bastard won't stop filling out syntax ones, such as when I open a bracket it already pastes the closed one. I want to learn properly, and that is to experience the problem with the missed syntax in order to make my learning process machine independent. Any clues?

By the way, manually setting "auto_complete": false did not help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> such as when I open a bracket it already pastes the closed one

In your user Preferences.sublime-settings set this to false.

```
"auto_match_enabled": true,
```

For the rest of your question, start looking through the system preferences file and copy those features your would like to set to false to your user preferences - things like

- `"smart_indent": true,`
- `"match_brackets": true,`
- `"tab_completion": true,`
- etc